# Creating a more flexible function

Tags: python

I am working with Python as a new student. I have made a function that is not particularly robust in its parameters and am hoping someone can help me make it more flexible.

It works with a list of dictionaries, each of which contains information about a student and their grades on assignments. All it needs to do is go through the list, average the student's grades and print the average. I can make it do that, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to make it more flexible in the number of assignments. I want it to be able to run the code and give an average regardless of how many assignments there are. Right now I see that it is only limited to three assignments existing.

Here is what I have so far:

```
student_list = [{'id': 12341, 'first_name': 'Alice', 'last_name': 'Anderson',
         'assignments': [('assignment_1', 0), ('assignment_2', 2), ('assignment_3', 4)]},
```

```
 {'id': 12342, 'first_name': 'Boris', 'last_name': 'Bank',
   'assignments': [('assignment_1', 1), ('assignment_2', 3), ('assignment_3', 0)]},

 {'id': 12343, 'first_name': 'Carl', 'last_name': 'Cape',
   'assignments': [('assignment_1', 2), ('assignment_2', 4), ('assignment_3', 1)]},

 {'id': 12344, 'first_name': 'Didi', 'last_name': 'Dawson',
   'assignments': [('assignment_1', 3), ('assignment_2', 0), ('assignment_3', 2)]},

 {'id': 12345, 'first_name': 'Ed', 'last_name': 'Enders',
   'assignments': [('assignment_1', 4), ('assignment_2', 1), ('assignment_3', 3)]}]
```

def average_grade(students):
    students = 'students'

`for i in range(len(student_list)):

   grade = student_list[i]['assignments'][0][1]+student_list[i]['assignments'][1][1]+\
           student_list[i]['assignments'][2][1]
   average = grade/3
   print('The average grade of ' + student_list[i]['first_name'] + str(' ') + student_list[i]['last_name']
   + str(' is ') + str(average))

average_grade('students')`

This give the output:

> The average grade of Alice Anderson is 2.0
>   The average grade of Boris Bank is 1.3333333333333333
>   The average grade of Carl Cape is 2.3333333333333335
>   The average grade of Didi Dawson is 1.6666666666666667
>   The average grade of Ed Enders is 2.6666666666666665

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure is fine, just instead of dividing by a set number to get your average use `len(i['assignments'])` this will allow you to generate the proper average regardless of amount of scores.

```
for i in student_list:
    grade = sum([j[1] for j in i['assignments']])
    average = grade/len(i['assignments'])
    print('The average grade of {} {} is {}'.format(i['first_name'], i['last_name'], round(average, 2)))
```

> ```
> The average grade of Alice Anderson is 2.0
> The average grade of Boris Bank is 1.33
> The average grade of Carl Cape is 2.33
> The average grade of Didi Dawson is 1.67
> The average grade of Ed Enders is 2.67
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The data structure is not great, but you can always use a list comprehension:

`grade = sum([assignment[1] for assignment in student_list[i]['assignments']])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested for loop, for example:

```
 for student in student_list:
    assignments = student.get('assignments')
    grade = 0
    for assignment in assignments:
        grade += assignment[1]
    avg_grade = grade / len(assignments)
    print(avg_grade)
```